# "Smart" way to concatenate strings?

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I'm looking for a "smart" way to concatenate strings with a separator. Obviously I could code all this out myself so I'm wondering if there is a simple way (LINQ or maybe some other method that I don't know) to do this.

Say I have a set of strings (this can be any number of strings):

```
string s1 = "a";
string s2 = "b";
string s3 = "c";
```

And I want to concatenate the strings such that the result is something like `a, b, c`. This is easy enough, but here's the twist: if any of the strings are empty, I don't want the extra comma.

For instance, if this is my set:

```
string s1 = "";
string s2 = "b";
string s3 = "c";
```

I want the result to be `b, c` (or just `c` if both `s1` and `s2` are empty).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: string.join    ......... maybe with a .where(s=>!string.isnullorempty(s)) thrown in

Comment: @pm100 That sounds great - can you answer with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string>{"a","b","", null};
var res = string.Join(", ", list.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```

Comment: Great! Very simple! (I edited it to fix the syntax and capitalization for you)

Answer (score 3):

```
string.Join(",", SOME_STRING_COLLECTION.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [string.Join(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string space = " ";
            string a = "One";
            string b = "Two";
            string c = "Three";
            var filteredList = (new List<string> { space, a, b, c }).Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
            string abc = string.Join(", ", filteredList);
            Console.WriteLine(abc); //One, Two, Three
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```